# Extjs how to define a project configuration file?

Tags: extjs

I have been testing Extjs for a while, and I want to create a global configuration file. I was looking into the official documentation how to create a configuration file for my project, I mean a file to place main constants, for instance, but I could not find how. Also I have been googling for this, but also unsuccessfully. What I found is how to set configuration for each component, like this:

```
config: {
        // my config
}
```

how to set this config:

```
Ext.apply(this, {
      config: {
          // set my config
      }
});
```

and the way to access it, for instance, calling it from any item listener:

```
var config = item.up().config;
```

It works for me, but only in the component scope. What I need to do something like this, but for the whole project. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Simply create a new `.js` file then put all your constantes in a global variable:

Config definition:

```
var ProjectConf = ProjectConf || {}
ProjectConf.MyConfig = {
    const1 = "myValue"
    //...
}
```

Then apply it when you need it:

```
Ext.apply(this, {
      config: ProjectConf.MyConfig
});
```

---

2. Or you can define a global config for each components with `override`.

For example for all view components:

```
Ext.define("Ext.locale.fr.view.View", {
    override: "Ext.view.View",
    config: {
        const1 = "myValue"
        // Will apply the config to all view
    }
});
```